# Best tutorials for R beginner?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, dataset, computational-statistics

Heyo-

I just started fooling around with R and want to find a good tutorial. Suggestions?

Also, are there other things I should be doing to beef up my R chops?

Context: very little coding experience, intermediate knowledge of SPSS

Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I recommad this site for really beginner :
http://tryr.codeschool.com/

It deals with : Syntax, Vectors, Matrices, Summary Statistics, Factors, Data Frames.